# GRASS Tools Panel (vers 8.3.1) in QGIS (vers 3.34.4): Filter button does not work

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

Here is a screenshot of what I am addressing. As you can see if I type any module's name I don't get any result.

How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using QGIS 3.34.4?